# PythonInterpreter in Jython - storing result

Tags: java, jython

I've redirected the console output to a txt file for the code below, however is there a way to assign the result to a local variable instead? e.g. if the output is 'Hello World' I'd like to assign this to a String variable.

I'm looking at the PythonInterpreter API and I am slightly confused as it's new to me 
(http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html).

I've been playing around with the setIn and setOut methods, but haven't got it working.

Would be very grateful for some advice.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an instance of the PythonInterpreter
    PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();

    // The exec() method executes strings of code
    interp.exec("import sys");
    interp.exec("print sys");

    interp.execfile("C:/Users/A/workspace/LeaerningPyDev/helloWorld.py");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the command-line output of the executed Python-script into a Java-String, first create a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html); let's call it `bout`. Then call
`interp.setOut(bout)`. After calling `interp.execfile(...)` you should be able to retrieve its output as a Java-String via `bout.toString()`.

However, in general it is more elegant not to do such stuff via the system-out/in. Instead you can use `interp.eval(some python expression)`, which returns the expression's result as a `PyObject`. On the `PyObject` you can use Jython-API to turn it into a corresponding Java standard-type or do whatever you want with it. If you want to use a more complex script (rather than a single expression), you can use `interp.get(variable name)` to retrive certain objects created by your script as `PyObject`s.

Comment: Hi stewori, thanks for the advice. I will give this a try.